# What ways are there to convert an Integer to a list of digits?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

How can I convert an `Integer` to list of numbers? For example:

```
781049 ==> {7, 8, 1, 0, 4, 9}
```

What are the possible ways of doing this? How well they compare performance-wise? Is a compiled version faster than `IntegerDigits`? How to convert huge amounts of large integers to digit form?

Comment: Have a look at `IntegerDigits`.

Comment: Or have a look at `ToString`, `Characters` and `ToExpression`, in this order.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/IntegerDigits.html

Comment: Sorry all: per [this meta discussion](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/277/89), I took the liberty to make a perhaps more useful question.

Comment: For speed, `IntegerDigits` is really the way to go about this.

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty easy if you understood that we live in a world of base 10 and the principles of division with rest:

```
n = 781049;
Rest@Reverse[Flatten@Last@Reap@FixedPointList[(Sow[Mod[#, 10]]; Quotient[#, 10]) &, n]]
(* {7, 8, 1, 0, 4, 9} *)
```

or as J.M. suggested with one call to get the quotient and the remainder

```
With[{n = 781049}, Reverse[Reap[NestList[Block[{q, r}, 
 {q, r} = QuotientRemainder[#, 10]; Sow[r]; q] &, n, IntegerLength[n]]][[-1, 1]]]]
```

If you really prefer shorter methods, than you could go with

```
IntegerDigits[n]
```

or maybe

```
ToExpression@StringCases[ToString[n], DigitCharacter]
```

if you like strings. Without giving explicit timings you can safely assume, that every function will be slower than `IntegerDigits`.

Comment: It might be nice to add timings to this question, given that István Zachar emphasized this. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

```
f[n_ /; n < 10] := {n};
f[n_] := f[Floor[n/10]]~Join~{n~Mod~10};

f[n0_] := Block[{n = n0, r = {}},
  While[n != 0,
   r = {n~Mod~10}~Join~r;
   n = Floor[n/10]];
  r
 ]

f /@ {123, 142857, 9876}
(*{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7}, {9, 8, 7, 6}}*)
```

Comment: `Floor[n/10]` is better written as `Quotient[n, 10]`.