# How can I make Which format its output?

Tags: front-end, functions, output-formatting

Functions like `Piecewise` have cool, easy-to-read formatting. In the same vein, I think it would be wonderful if the `Which` function automatically returned output in a column or tabulated form:

```
 Which[a < b,     1,
       c < d,     2, 
       True,      3]
```

rather than the what currently happens, which can sometimes be difficult to read.

```
Which[a < b, 1, c < d, 2, True, 3]
```

This example happens to be easy to read, but for `Which` expressions with a large number of `<condition, value>` pairs, it would be nice to have a structured layout for the output.

Any suggestions as to how to make this happen automatically?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`$Post`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$Post.html) is handy but it can get confusing when you want to use it for many things at once.

I propose using [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MakeBoxes.html) for this kind of thing as it is specifically intended for specifying formatted (Box) output.

[`Interpretation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpretation.html) is used to make the output work correctly as input.

The right-hand-side of the definition can be either explicit `*Box` expressions or you can use `ToBoxes` to convert "normal" expressions to box form.

```
MakeBoxes[p : Which[x__], fmt_] := 
 Interpretation[
   Row @ {Which, MatrixForm @ Partition[Defer /@ Unevaluated[{x}], 2]},
   p
 ] ~ToBoxes~ fmt

Which[a < b, 1, c < d, 2, True, 3]
```

[image]

Alternatively with square brackets:

```
MakeBoxes[p : Which[x__], fmt_] := 
 Interpretation[
   Style[HoldForm[Which][Grid @ Partition[List @@ Defer /@ Hold[x], 2]], SpanMaxSize -> ∞],
   p
 ] ~ToBoxes~ fmt

Which[a < b, Print@1, c < d, Print@2, True, Print@3]
```

[image]

(Incidentally `List @@ Defer /@ Hold[x]` and `Defer /@ Unevaluated[{x}]` are two ways to do the same thing; take your pick for which is easier to read.)

Comment: Very cool - especially the square bracket version. One wonders why this is not built-in to Mma? ... at least for 30 rows or less.

Comment: @Rojo Please let me know if you see any other/new problems with my current code.

Answer (score 8):

When I want to modify an output then first thing that comes to mind is `$Post`.

```
$Post = If[Head[#] === Which, 
                             Row[{Which, MatrixForm@Partition[List @@ #, 2]}],
                             #] &;

Which[a < b, 1, c < d, 2, True, 3]
```

> [image]

Moreover, there is nothing to prevent you from using the `2D input` interface with `Which`. You only have to be aware what you are writing.

So using standard <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> with <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> you can write like this:

[image]

And, if you haven't reset `$Post=.` from what I showed above, the output will be:

> [image]

Comment: Wow Kuba, `$Post` is great stuff :). This is no ordinary plotting ;).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Quite interesting, but I suspect it is going to make some troubles when overdosed :) First faced [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26154/5478)