# Formatting All Appropriate Output as Desired Automatically

Tags: matrix, output-formatting

I want to output in `MatrixForm` whenever I have a list/vector/matrix, but I do not want to have to type out the command each time.

How can I write one command at the beginning of the notebook so that all output is so formatted?  (Also: generalization to any formatting would be better, with additional specific detail included for this case.)

Comment: [closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28868/5478)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$Post`:

```
$Post = If[ArrayQ@#, MatrixForm@#, #] &;
```

> [image]

Comment: Is this what you are after?

Comment: I think that that will do just fine!  Thank you! (Could you explain what each part of that code does?  Mathematica Documentation can confuse me easily and I like to be able to have multiple sources of explanation for the code.)

Comment: @kevin There is not much there, what is that you have problems with? Have you seen [`$Post`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$Post.html)?