# All output in TexForm

Tags: output-formatting

In the Preferences -> Evaluation panel, there are only options for `StandardForm`, `TraditionalForm` and `Output Form`. So I have to write `// TexForm` every time after my code.

Can anyone tell me to get *Mathematica* yp always output in `TexForm`?

Comment: You can use `$Post`: [Formatting All Appropriate Output as Desired Automatically](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46135/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Thank you, then this should be $Post = TeXForm@# &;

Comment: Or simply `$Post = TeXForm`